# Inline eslint comment in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I'm getting an error `(eslint): Line 199 exceeds maximum line length of 120. (max-len)`

Why doesn't this inline comment work?

```
{/* eslint-disable-next-line max-len */}
<Chip ref="code" style={styles.chip}backgroundColor={this.state.filterSelected['School Code'] && blue300}onTouchTap={this.handleTouchTap} >
            <Avatar size={32}>C</Avatar>
            School Code
</Chip>
```

Comment: The comment should work fine, the error is about the length of the second line, as specified in your eslint config

Comment: Works fine for me with ESLint 4.19.1.

Comment: The only thing that worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62277579/2884291

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`eslint-disable-line` and `eslint-disable-next-line` are only in inline comments.

There is currently an open issue for this in [eslint](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/7030)

So you would have to write it as the following:

```
{
  // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
}<Chip ref="code" style={styles.chip}backgroundColor={this.state.filterSelected['School Code'] && blue300}onTouchTap={this.handleTouchTap} >
            <Avatar size={32}>C</Avatar>
            School Code
</Chip>
```

Comment: The linked issue has since been closed -- however, it seems that many find the resolution less than complete-- if so, you can thumbs up this comment: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/7030#issuecomment-290866531

Answer (score 8):

Daniel's answer works fine, but it breaks "jsx-one-expression-per-line".

Latest version of eslint (6.5.1) supports the multi-line comment method as shown in question. There isn't need to change anything.

Answer (score 1):

If maybe happens that you are using a conditional before the jsx you want to disable eslint you could do this (without the need of { } just for the comment line):

```
condition && (
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    <Component props={...props} />
      {...children}
    </Component>
  )
```

Comment: Not quite sure in which other situations this trick would work

Answer (score 1):

If you have work with code formatter like prettier, the answer below won't work because code formatter will force ugly code like that.

```
{
  // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
}<Chip ref="code" style={styles.chip}backgroundColor={this.state.filterSelected['School Code'] && blue300}onTouchTap={this.handleTouchTap} >
            <Avatar size={32}>C</Avatar>
            School Code
</Chip>
```

I think this solution will work with 'prettier' code.

```
{
  // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
  <Chip ref="code" style={styles.chip}backgroundColor={this.state.filterSelected['School Code'] && blue300}onTouchTap={this.handleTouchTap} >
              <Avatar size={32}>C</Avatar>
              School Code
  </Chip>
}
```

Comment: I needed to use `// prettier-ignore` as the unnecessary block was causing trouble

Answer (score 0):

Tried all other solutions (including those on [closed issue](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/7030)), but it didn't work on multi-lined attributes.

This worked for me:

```
{// eslint-disable-next-line
}<a
  ...
 >
 </a>
```

Example:

```
<div>
{// eslint-disable-next-line
}<a
  role="button"
  class="navbar-burger burger"
  aria-label="menu"
  aria-expanded="false"
  data-target="navbarBasicExample"
  >
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </a>
<div>
```