# Disable eslint error in jsx

Tags: react-native, reactjs, eslint

I have the below JSX in one of my react-native components

```
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onEnableNotifications} style={{marginHorizontal: 10}}>
          <Image source={require('../../img/ic_warning.png')} style={{tintColor: colorThemes.Blue.red}}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

I get the following ESLint error:

```
'require' is not defined. (no-undef)
```

I have tried adding line `{ // eslint-disable-line no-undef }` after `Image` but that gives a parsing error. How can I get rid of this error just for that line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On your `.eslintrc` file:

```
{
    "globals":{
        "require": true
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @Eldelsheel, thanks for the answer. I was trying to find what does the above line do but didn't find anything on ESLint documentation. Does the above line define the `require` function globally?

Comment: yes, like global names ESLint won't bother you with. Other examples: `__DEV__`, `$`, etc

Comment: Great tip, I was able to get rid of same error for `Promise` and `__DEV__` using this. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In order to disable eslint warnings with comments inside jsx use

```
{ /* eslint-disable no-undef */ }
     <div>element causing warning </div>
{ /* eslint-enable no-undef */ }
```

A single line comment does not work:

```
{ /* eslint-disable-line no-undef */ }
```

Also see

https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/7030

Answer (score 3):

I've read there are some jsx [quirks](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/7030) so try separating it out:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onEnableNotifications} style={{marginHorizontal: 10}}>
  <Image
    source={require('../../img/ic_warning.png')} // eslint-disable-line no-undef
    style={{tintColor: colorThemes.Blue.red}}
  />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Or you can define it above.

```
const warningImage = require('../../img/ic_warning.png'); // eslint-disable-line no-undef

....

<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onEnableNotifications} style={{marginHorizontal: 10}}>
  <Image source={warningImage} style={{tintColor: colorThemes.Blue.red}}/>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

If this is a static path though, I would just define it outside the react class/function entirely, as an import.

Answer (score 1):

To disable an eslint rule on an attribute, you can use an inline comment:

```
<StatusBar
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/style-prop-object
  style='light'
/>
```